# Почему в винительном падеже только "о борт", но не "об борт"?

Tags: предлоги

Правила, конечно, почитывал.

> в винительном падеже перед словами, начинающимися согласными (кроме
> форм местоименных слов все, всю, все, всех, что), употребляются
> предлоги «о» и «об»: ударился о камень и об камень

https://www.ekburg.ru/news/18/65341-kak-pravilno-upotreblyat-predlogi-o--ob-i-obo/

Слово «борт» начинается с Б, а это согласная буква. Но почему-то не думаю, что поэт когда-либо напишет: "Волны бились об борт корабля". Или всё-таки это допустимый вариант, кто знает?

Comment: Национальный корпус русского языка [свидетельствует](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=об+борт) о том, что «об борт» – это допустимый вариант.

Comment: @Yellow Sky 2 примера в корпусе на самом деле ни о чем не свидетельствуют. Для примера, слово "ложить" появляется в 98 примерах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оба варианта допустимы (как минимум) в разговорной речи, а уж тем более в стихотворении, русскоязычные поэты часто идут и на большие "грехи" ради метрики. Аналогично тому, как в английском, когда можно сказать "an" многие говорят просто "а", со многими словами по факту говорят "о", ну например "он облокотился о барную стойку" или "об".